F# compiler signatures
Question about the signatures of delay1 and delay2 functions
delay1: (unit -> 'a) -> unit -> 'a
delay2: (unit -> 'a) -> (unit -> 'a)
of the below snippet.
The functions seem to output the same thing (a function that maps unit-to-'a), but in the first case it's wrapped in parentheses while in the the second one it's not.
What could explain that?
module ToDelete = 

    let delay1 (funcToDelay) = 
        fun () -> funcToDelay ()
    
    let delayedResult1 = delay1 (fun () -> Some 1)

    printfn "delayedResult1: %A" (delayedResult1 ())


    printfn "==========================================="
    

    let delay2 (funcToDelay) = 
        let delayedResult = funcToDelay ()
        fun () -> delayedResult
    
    let delayedResult2 = delay1 (fun () -> Some 2)

    printfn "delayedResult2: %A" (delayedResult2 ())


The two signatures are equivalent. So, both are correct. With the intermediate expression and binding, type checking just runs a little different and thus finds a function with one parameter, returning a function, while in the first case it finds a partial function.
Contentwise, of course, the second version does not delay the function.
